# JSF form onload reset() functionality not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using the jsf along with primefaces. I want to call reset functionality when my form loads. But so far i am unable to achieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reset(){

      alert("dsdsd");
      document.getElementById('A1938:create-ticket').reset();
       }
     window.onload=function(){reset();};
   </script>

<h:form id="create-ticket">
           <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Select different user" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true">

              <ui:include src="searchpopup.xhtml" />
         </p:dialog>
```

which definately not gona work as jsf translates the page in different way. Any idea.

The alert is getting called.So again i want the form to reset itself when it gets loaded similar to form.reset()

thanks,
Cyd

Comment: Post whole code for that form. We can't guess how it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Calling reset when the page loads makes no utter sense. Perhaps you misunderstood the meaning of `reset()`. The `form.reset()` does not **clear** the input fields, instead it **resets** the input values to their initial values. I.e. when you get a form with prefilled inputs and then change them, then the `reset()` would reinitialize them with initial values as it was when the page was loaded. So, the form would only be cleared out on `reset()` when the initial values are *already* empty by itself.

So, to achieve your concrete functional requirement, you need to clear out the bean properties directly instead of fiddling with `form.reset()` which doesn't do what you think it does. Or, better, put the bean in the request or view scope and make sure that the form is opened by a fresh new GET request.